# AsExpression Removes Undefined from Type More Aggressively Than I'd Like

Tags: typescript

I am using an API that returns a base type. I use the `as` keyword to coerce the type over to a union of two sub-types of that base type.

```
interface base { a: number; }
interface sub1 extends base { s1: number; }
interface sub2 extends base { s2: number; }
interface sub3 extends base { s3: number; }

declare function returns1or2(): base;

const x = returns1or2() as sub1 | sub2;

console.log(x.a);
```

This is fine/great and what I want.

The "problem" with the `AsExpression` I'm using here is if the API's declaration changes as it grows more `--strictNullChecks`-awesome, someone might change it's return type to:

```
declare function returns1or2(): base | undefined;

const x = returns1or2() as sub1 | sub2;

console.log(x.a);  // now a run-time error (in some situations)
```

And that never show up as a compile-time error for me (the API consumer), making me scared to use the `AsExpression`.

Is there some other pattern I should be using/attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it can be solved by adding a level of indirection. You can define your own function that does the cast and does not accept `undefined`:

```
interface base { a: number; }
interface sub1 extends base { s1: number; }
interface sub2 extends base { s2: number; }
interface sub3 extends base { s3: number; }

declare function returns1or2(): base | undefined;

function castFromTo<From, To extends From>(from: From): To { return from as To };


const x = castFromTo<base, sub1 | sub2>(returns1or2());//error with strictNullChecks 
//Argument of type 'base | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'base'
//      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'base'.
```